# Python Requests Not Pulling Correct URL

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I am trying to write a script that goes to https://etfdb.com/etfs/asset-class/equity/#etfs&sort_name=assets_under_management&sort_order=desc&page=1 and pulls all ETFs listed on the website. If you visit the page you will see that there are 82 pages containing information. You can use the URL parameter to get to any page and if you enter a page that does not exist it defaults to page 1. Whenever I change the URL in the request call I continue to get the same information as page 1, while when I type the same URL into a browser I am able to see a new page with new information. For example, `requests.get("https://etfdb.com/etfs/asset-class/equity/#etfs&sort_name=assets_under_management&sort_order=desc&page=61")`returns the same HTML as if I entered `page=1`, although, when I copy and paste the URL into my browser it shows me page 61. When I inspect the request object it has reponse 200, false for redirect and the URL field is the correct one I want to pull, but the information still matches the first page. I've looked through the html and have seen no token or authentication variable(although it may be obfuscated so I cant see).
I was wondering if anyone knows why the request keeps pulling the first page and ignoring the URL parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So the actual data is coming from an API
Try this for page 1:

```
import requests


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://etfdb.com/etfs/asset-class/equity/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
}

response = requests.get('https://etfdb.com/data_set/?tm=92718&cond={%22by_type%22:[%22Etfdb::EtfType%22,17,null,false,false]}&no_null_sort=true&count_by_id=&limit=25&sort=assets_under_management&order=desc&limit=25&offset=25', headers=headers)
```

Then for page two, increase the offset to 50 in `&offset=25`.
If you want to scrape all of them, you can change the 'limit' param or divide the 'total' that is returned in the json response of the first 25 and iterate ~total/25 times. Ill leave it to you

Comment: Thanks for the help! Where did you find the documentation for this? Was wondering if I could get more insight as to how you knew to use this url in the request?

Comment: There isn't much documentation for this kind of thing. But as a general rule, I tend look on the network tab in the developer tools when the page is static and the data changes. Look for response types of json, then look at the json response to see if thats the data you want. Other wise you can use a webdrive like selenium. If this helps, upvote.

Comment: So turns out the website changes the link everyday. Do you know of any way to do it by using the common URL in the original post? Or a way to capture network responses on the website?

Comment: Yes I have found a way.
res = requests.get('https://etfdb.com/etfs/asset-class/equity/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
aum_table = soup.find('table',{'data-sort-name':'assets_under_management'})
aum_table['data-url']. From there you can find the url